# Stanford CoreNLP - Unknown variable: WEEKDAY

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I process the NYT portion of the English Gigaword Corpus with Stanford CoreNLP. While it is still on-going the following message is logged several times:

`Unknown variable: WEEKDAY`

Every time this message is logged the memory consumption increases. It is now about 23.8GB. Does someone know what this issue is about?

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0 from Github with commit id `4fd28dc4848616e568a2dd6eeb09b9769d1e3f4e` and the following models `stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models`. My pipeline looks like the this: `"annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, depparse, mention, coref"`.

I already know [this](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2014-March/005235.html) question. But no one has answered.

Comment: Ouch! Well, 2 people have the problem so it must be real, but I don't know the answer. WEEKDAY is defined in `english.sutime.txt` and `SUTime.java`. Do you see a logged message when loading that says `Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt` and then `INFO: Read 267 rules`? Can you provide a command-line or properties file and a document that causes this error?

Comment: Thanks for investigation! [Here's](http://pastebin.com/eeU1NfBF) a full log that contains all messages since I started the pipeline. I cannot provide the documents since the Gigaword corpus is licensed. But find [here](http://pastebin.com/rRJvrxa5) sample code and the respective corpus file names. However, I need to correct myself the code is using the latest CoreNLP and models available via maven.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We have English Gigaword, so if you know a particular file or document ID that causes the problem, that'd help narrow it down, but otherwise we can start here.

Comment: I have no "current file processing" log message. My mistake. The sentence "[..] fascinating field of quantum physic [...]" that causes the coref error in the log is from the document "NYT_ENG_20060202.0103". So I guess the file "NYT_ENG_20060202" could trigger the "WEEKDAY" issue. Otherwise try "NYT_ENG_20060201" that is processed after this one. I'm not sure which concrete document triggers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be resolved with this pull-request: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/pull/277

Comment: Or in other words, this was fixed in CoreNLP v3.7 forward.