# Stanford CoreNLP - Unknown variable WORKDAY

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am processing some documents and I am getting many WORKDAY messages as seen below.
There's a similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449826/stanford-corenlp-unknown-variable-weekday) for WEEKDAY. Does anyone know how to deal with this message. I am running corenlp in a Java server on Windows and accessing it using Juypyter Notebook  and Python code.

```
[pool-2-thread-2] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.types.Expressions - Unknown variable: WORKDAY
[pool-2-thread-2] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.types.Expressions - Unknown variable: WORKDAY
[pool-2-thread-2] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.types.Expressions - Unknown variable: WORKDAY
[pool-1-thread-7] WARN CoreNLP - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error making document
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error in the current SUTime rules file (and it's actually been there for quite a few versions). If you want to fix it immediately, you can do the following. Or we'll fix it in the next release. These are Unix commands, but the same thing will work elsewhere except for how you refer to and create folders.

Find this line in `sutime/english.sutime.txt` and delete it. Save the file.

`{ (/workday|work day|business hours/) => WORKDAY }`

Then move the file to the right location for replacing in the jar file, and then replace it in the jar file. In the root directory of the CoreNLP distribution do the following (assuming you don't already have an `edu` file/folder in that directory):

```
mkdir -p edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime
cp sutime/english.sutime.txt edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime
jar -uf stanford-corenlp-4.2.0-models.jar edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
rm -rf edu
```

Comment: Thank you so much Christopher! In my case, they went away after I thoroughly cleaned the documents. Exactly how clean are the documents supposed to be before processing them with coreNLP? My documents were read from pdf reports.

Comment: CoreNLP attempts to be reasonably robust to processing any test, so things don't have to be excessively clean. This was a genuine bug in the english sutime rules. The commonest problem running on very unclear text is arbitrarily long "sentences" when you get huge numbers of words without any sentence ender. In such cases, you often need to pass a "maxlen" to some of the annotators.